# i have this XML and i want to get image from this Image View against id

Tags: android

i have this XML and i want to get image from this Image View against id **detail_prfImagView** and save them into variable.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/detail_prfImagView"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Comment: you mean the image drawable/bitmap inside the ImageView? or the ImageView itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in your activity, after you have called `setViewContent`:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImgaeView) findViewById(R.id.detail_prfImagView);
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the bitmap associated with the `ImageView`, you can use `getDrawable`

```
ImageView imageView = (ImgaeView) findViewById(R.id.detail_prfImagView);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if (imageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
     bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
}
```